# Trying to copy one file with Amazon S3 CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I made a folder with 3 .jpg files in it to test.  This folder is called c:\Work\jpg.

I am trying to upload it to a bucket with this command:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://{bucket}/Test
```

I get the following every time:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\Work\jpg\".

Obviously, it correctly translated the current folder "." into the correct folder, but then it says it doesn't exist?!?

Any help out there to simply copy 3 files?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you confusing `aws s3 sync` with `aws s3 cp`. For copy, you need to specify the source file. The destination file can be current directory.

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt
```

Comment: Yes.  This is it.  I was confused by Linux examples with files without extensions thinking they were folders.  You are right.  I can use cp with a single file or sync with multiple with include and exclude.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that your path  is correctly written.
Remember add `--recursive` option, because is folder

```
aws s3 cp ./ s3://{bucket}/Test --recursive
```

Comment: I'm using Windows, but this doesn't work either.  Forward or backward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="aws-access-key" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="aws-secret-access" aws s3 --endpoint-url "s3 url" cp test.txt s3://bucket-name/path/test.txt